# Where can I find php.ini?

Tags: php, linux, php-ini

Today I needed to install the IBM DB2 library.  I went through all the steps up to `make install`, and I found ibm_db2.so in `$PHP_HOME/lib/extensions/somecomplicatedname/ibm_db2.so`.

The great catch is the last step is to configure file *php.ini*, but there aren't ***any*** *php.ini* files on my system. PHP works fine, except of course for this newfangled ibm_db2 thingamajig. (I tried a small PHP script which fails and indicates that the ibm_db2 functions are not available.)

How would I go about finding or setting up the php.ini file so that I can enable the library I need?

Comment: 90% of the time it's /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/q/2750580/632951

Comment: The premise of the question is wrong. _"there is NO php.ini on my system"_ No, you simply failed to locate it. Speaking of which, `locate php.ini` will tell you in mere moments where the file is on your system.

Comment: @Adam: unless it isn't PHP5 ;)

Comment: If you're on PHP 7 look @ /etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini

Comment: `php -i | grep "Loaded Configuration File" | sed 's#.* ##' | xargs vim` for easy editing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35211463/8144311), as of **PHP 7** the regular php.ini file was **removed** and added with `php.ini-production` and `php.ini-devlopment`.

so instead of php.ini which does not exist in my case (I've installed php 8.1), use `php.ini-production` and it's located in php installation folder (something like: `C:\PHP-8.1.5`) and create a file and name it `php.ini` and then copy contents of `php.ini-production` in this new `php.ini`.

Answer (score 1083):

On the command line execute:

```
php --ini
```

You will get something like:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /etc/php5/cli
Loaded Configuration File:         /etc/php5/cli/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: /etc/php5/cli/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed:      /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/curl.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/pdo.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/pdo_sqlite.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/sqlite.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/sqlite3.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/xdebug.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/xsl.ini
```

That's from my local dev-machine. However, the second line is the interesting one. If there is nothing mentioned, have a look at the first one. That is the path, where PHP looks for the `php.ini` file.

You can grep the same information using [phpinfo()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php) in a script and call it with a browser. It’s mentioned in the first block of the output. `php -i` does the same for the command line, but it’s quite uncomfortable.

Comment: accepting oldest and previously the simplest answer (SO forces me to wait a while before accepting). thanks for the expansion which will probably help the next person looking for information. for me the 2nd line said (none), and everything worked fine after putting a php.ini file in the path on the first line. thanks!

Comment: I used this command and edited the php.ini file that it directed me too and my PHP settings were not changing and I realized it was not giving me the correct php.ini file.  I tried using the phpinfo() PHP function and it give me the actual correct location of the php.ini I needed to edit.  I think this is very important and I hope this helps someone.

Comment: @thecommonthread Thank you for pointing out the problem you encountered in practice. I have changed the accepted answer to one that highlights creating a `.php` file. By the way, if you comment on the question then I get notified and I can fix the problem sooner.

Comment: @KingCrunch, Are you sure this is going to work when you have more than one PHP installation?

Comment: @Pacerier Yes. Just make sure you execute the right executable: `/path/to/one/php --ini` and `/path/to/another/php --ini`.

Comment: @KingCrunch, Then what about [thecommonthread's comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8684609/dude-wheres-my-php-ini#comment37497172_8684638) above?

Comment: @Pacerier This has nothing to do with different PHP installations, but the different SAPIs can use different ini files. I don't use the apache module, but as far as I remember I think there is no way around a `phpinfo.php`-like file. With FPM you can at least use `php5-fpm -i | grep '\.ini'`. Usually you use this two or three times and at the end of the day you _know_ where the files are ;)

Comment: Also on some lamp stacks this will return you only the php-cli php-ini.

Comment: I ended up editing the wrong ini file too, wasting an hour. This may be my own stupidity, but this is a warning to people like me- if it's not working create a <?php phpinfo(); ?> as above because that fixed it for me

Comment: /etc/php/8.2/apache2/php.ini is the desired one
php --ini  dont show

Answer (score 546):

The best way to find this is:

Create a PHP (*.php*) file and add the following code:

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

and open it in a browser. It will show the file which is actually being read!

Updates by the OP:

1. The previously accepted [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8684609/dude-wheres-my-php-ini/8684638#8684638) is likely to be faster and more convenient for you, but it is not always correct. See comments on that answer.
2. Please also note the more convenient alternative `<?php echo php_ini_loaded_file(); ?>` mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8684609/dude-wheres-my-php-ini/24342463#24342463).

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. If you have CLI installed and have apache running then it may have its own ini file (as my system does). Using the accepted answer returns what the CLI is using rather than apache's.

Comment: @Dan Yes, you are right. I am changing the accepted answer to this one because the problem you mention was also encountered somebody in practice (who commented on the previously accepted answer). (By the way, if you had commented on the question I would have fixed this problem sooner.)

Comment: This does not work on my installation. Typo? Should be `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`

Comment: `php -r \@phpinfo\(\)\;` works for me `php -r \@phpinfo\(\)\; | grep 'PHP Version' -m 1` to pull specific info

Comment: @zylstra Try: `<?php echo php_ini_loaded_file(); ?>`

Comment: the problem with this is when php does not want to load

Comment: maybe mention the very convenient `php -i | grep "Loaded Configuration File" | sed 's#.* ##' | xargs vim` for easy editing or `php -i | grep "Loaded Configuration File" | sed 's#.* ##' | xargs cat` for easy displaying?

Comment: Re *"it will show the file which is actually being read"*: Can you be more specific [in your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/17185370/edit) what to look for? E.g., is it the line with *"Loaded Configuration File"*?

Answer (score 167):

This works for me:

```
php -i | grep 'php.ini'
```

You should see something like:

```
Loaded Configuration File => /usr/local/lib/php.ini
```

P.S.

To get only the php.ini path, use:

```
php -i | grep /.+/php.ini -oE
```

Comment: This only works, if there _is_ a `php.ini`, which is exactly the problem: If there is none, you still don't know where to look at, or where to place a new one.

Comment: I've never come across a situation where there is no php.ini file.

Comment: Running this command gives me `Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /usr/lib`, but running `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` gives me `Loaded Configuration File: /etc/php.ini`.  So, `phpinfo()` was more reliable in my case.

Comment: This is not entirely correct. Every framework that uses the PHP language has it's own php.ini file. If you call that line from the command line, you will probably end up receiving something like /var/php5/cli/php.ini which is not the file used when running PHP on a web environment. For that file, you should look into the apache2 folder.

Comment: is possible get the output `php -i | grep 'php.ini'` from apache? (script.php)

Answer (score 74):

In a command window, type

```
php --ini
```

It will show you the path something like:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /usr/local/lib
Loaded Configuration File:         /usr/local/lib/php.ini
```

If the above command does not work then use this:

```
echo phpinfo();
```

Answer (score 43):

Use the following command to find the `php.ini` file path on Linux.

```
locate php.ini
```

Output:

```
/etc/php.ini
/etc/php.ini.rpmnew
/usr/share/doc/php-common-5.4.45/php.ini-development
/usr/share/doc/php-common-5.4.45/php.ini-production
```

Or try this other way:

```
php --ini
```

It shows the path result.

Comment: This is inferior to methods like `php -i | grep 'php.ini'`, because it finds *any* php.ini and doesn’t tell you which one your PHP installation uses. Also, it may give wrong results when the `locate` DB is not up to date.

Comment: `locate` is not installed by default on [Ubuntu MATE 20.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_MATE#Releases) (Focal Fossa).

Answer (score 36):

This command should help you to find it

```
php -r "phpinfo();" | grep php.ini
```

Comment: I like this a lot more than some of the other answers.  It doesn't require that I create, locate a php file with those contents and load up the page in the browser.

Answer (score 31):

PHP comes with two native functions to show which configuration file is loaded:

- [php_ini_loaded_file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.php-ini-loaded-file.php) returns the loaded .ini file
- [php_ini_scanned_files](http://php.net/manual/en/function.php-ini-scanned-files.php) returns a list of .ini files parsed from the additional ini directory

Depending on your setup, **Apache** and **CLI** might use different .ini files. Here are the two solutions:

### Apache:

Just add the following in a PHP (.php) file and open it in your browser:

```php
print php_ini_loaded_file();
print_r(php_ini_scanned_files());
```

### CLI:

Copy-paste in your terminal:

```
php -r 'print php_ini_loaded_file(); print_r(php_ini_scanned_files());'
```

Comment: Under-appreciated, thorough, and (almost) correct answer. I almost switched this to the correct answer but I am worried that `php_ini_loaded_file` may not always be available.

Comment: @zylstra what was your php version? the docs for `php_ini_loaded_file` say php version >= 5.2.4

Comment: @necromancer Not sure now. Forgot which system I was checking.  :/

Answer (score 27):

```
phpinfo();
```

will tell you its location, or from the command line

```
php -i
```

Answer (score 22):

**Try one of these solutions**

1. In your terminal, type `find / -name "php.ini"`
2. In your terminal, type  `php -i | grep php.ini`. It should show the file path as *"Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /etc"*
3. If you can access one of your PHP files, open it in a editor ([Notepad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notepad_%28software%29)) and insert `phpinfo();` after `<?php` on a new line. This will tell you the *php.ini* location.
4. You can also talk to PHP in interactive mode. Just type `php -a` in the terminal and type `phpinfo();` after the PHP interpreter initiated.

Comment: points 1, 2, and 4 are vulnerable to multiple installation problems;  there are already great answers. no need to add an answer that doesn't add anything here.

Answer (score 21):

Run this in the command line:

```
php -r "echo php_ini_loaded_file().PHP_EOL;"
```

Answer (score 7):

```
find / -name php.ini
```

Hey... it worked for me!

Comment: for one, it takes a while; for two, if you have more than one, how do you know which is the one actually in use?

Comment: True, `php --ini` works, but this is just another option :)

There is usually a `/etc/php5/cli/php.ini`
`/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini`
`/etc/php5/cgi/php.ini` and usually which one you want is pretty obvious. (cli, apache, cgi)

Comment: This is not a good solution, because we are not intended to find all the php.ini file on disk.

Answer (score 4):

You can get more information about your configuration files using something like:

```
$ -> php -i | ack config # Use fgrep -i if you don't have ack

Configure Command =>  './configure'  ...
Loaded Configuration File => /path/to/php.ini
```

Answer (score 4):

For [SAPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Application_Programming_Interface): php-fpm

There isn't any need to create a *php.info* file (it is not a good policy to leave it for the world to read anyway). On the command line:

```
php-fpm -i | more
```

Somewhere in its output, it will show this line:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /etc
```

Here is a more complete explanation:
*[How to Figure out Your PHP Configuration Parameters without info.php](https://www.cloudinsidr.com/content/how-to-figure-out-your-php-configuration-parameters-without-info-php/)*