# Parse error: Syntax error, unexpected end of file in my PHP code

Tags: php, html, parse-error

I got an error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in the line
```

With this code:

```
<html>
    <?php
        function login()
        {
            // Login function code
        }
        if (login())
    {?>

    <h2>Welcome Administrator</h2>
    <a href=\"upload.php\">Upload Files</a>
    <br />
    <a href=\"points.php\">Edit Points Tally</a>

    <?php}
        else
        {
            echo "Incorrect login details. Please login";
        }
    ?>
    Some more HTML code
</html>
```

What's the problem?

Comment: I would imagine you have an error with some of your PHP code... which you haven't posted.

Comment: It sounds like you have a missing '}', ';' or bracket but it would help if you posted you whole php code

Comment: Please post a [*complete* example](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: As @Ryanc1256 mentioned, it is most probably a case of missing bracket. Do include the actual code with the question, if you really want a solution.

Comment: You may need to change `<?` to `<?php`

Comment: A year and a half hence, it is funny that this question was closed because it is too localized but it has got almost 50k views.

Comment: I agree...this totally fixed my problem.  Not localized at all in regards to the question and the solution.

Comment: Also check for `short_tags` in your php.ini under BOTH `apache` and `cli` configs

Comment: cat /etc/php.ini | grep short_open_tag

Comment: I got this error in my code, and it turned out it was because of a semicolon after an `if` condition: `if ($var = 'value');{ ... } else { ... }`

Answer (score 368, accepted):

You should avoid this (at the end of your code):

```
{?>
```

and this:

```
<?php}
```

You shouldn't put brackets directly close to the open/close `php` tag, but separate it with a space:

```
{ ?>
<?php {
```

also avoid `<?` and use `<?php`

Comment: In case it helps anybody: I got a similar error, but caused by `<? } ?>` instead of `<?php } ?>`.

Comment: I had similar ptoblem but my case was that i had short_open_tag = Off in my php.ini. When i turned it to On, my code worked.

Comment: Note while Apache accepts this Nginx does not (or rather fcgi does not) so if your stumped by why this is working on one web server and not another you know why

Comment: Can you add to avoid also this <?php //echo $pagetitle; ?> the comment slashes are killing the closing ?>

Comment: Is there a reason `<?` and `<?=` should be avoided? I was taught them as useful shorthands.

Comment: @HashimAziz read https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/151661/is-it-bad-practice-to-use-tag-in-php

Comment: That little by the way "use <?php instead of <?" just fixed an issue I lost hours on! Thank you so very much!

Answer (score 117):

I had the same error, but I had it fixed by modifying the `php.ini` file.

Find your php.ini file see [Dude, where's my php.ini?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8684609/dude-wheres-my-php-ini)

then open it with your favorite editor.

Look for a `short_open_tag` property, and apply the following change:

```
; short_open_tag = Off ; previous value
short_open_tag = On ; new value
```

Comment: This answer is especially important when dealing with legacy code. I have inherited code written by someone else, and the codebase was full of of `<? ?>` (note, the missing `php`). I am tasked to add or change features, and it typically isn't a good idea to just go around changing *everything* just for one or two features. Your answer really helped.

Comment: Spot on, this is especially noteworthy if you have upgraded to the newer Plesk hosting software for instance or upgraded your PHP version.  We found the php.ini settings got trashed and we had to go through set them again, this particular one was required to avoid the unexpected end of file error

Answer (score 41):

> I had the same error, but I had it fixed by modifying the php.ini and / or editing the PHP file!

There are two different methods to get around the parse error syntax.

#### Method 1 (Your PHP file)

Avoid in your PHP file this:

```
<? } ?>
```

Make sure you put it like this

```
<?php ?>
```

> Your code contains `<? ?>`
>
> ***NOTE:*** **The missing `php` after `<?`!**

#### Method 2 (php.ini file)

There is also a simple way to solve your problem.
Search for the `short_open_tag` property value *(Use in your text editor with `Ctrl + F`!)*, and apply the following change:

```
; short_open_tag = Off
```

to

```
short_open_tag = On
```

According to the [description of core php.ini directives](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag), `short_open_tag` allows you to use the short open tag (`<?`) although **this might cause issues when used with xml (`<?xml` will not work when this is enabled)!**

> ***NOTE:*** **Reload your Server *(like for example: Apache)* and reload your PHP webpage in your browser.**

Answer (score 15):

Just go to php.ini then find `short_open_tag= Off` set to `short_open_tag= On`

Answer (score 14):

## Also, watch out for heredoc closing identifiers.

**Invalid Example:**

```php
// it's not working!!!

function findAll() {
    $query=<<<SQL
        SELECT * FROM `table_1`;
    SQL; // <-------- THIS IS BAD

    // ...
}
```

This will throw an exception that resembles the following:

```
<br />
<b>Parse error</b>:  syntax error, unexpected end of file in <b>[...][...]</b> on line <b>5</b><br />
```

where number 5 might be the last line number of your file.

**According to [php manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php):**

> **Warning**
> It is very important to note that the line with the closing identifier must contain no other characters, except a semicolon (;). That means especially that the identifier may not be indented, and there may not be any spaces or tabs before or after the semicolon. It's also important to realize that the first character before the closing identifier must be a newline as defined by the local operating system. This is \n on UNIX systems, including macOS. The closing delimiter must also be followed by a newline.

***TLDR***: Closing identifiers should **NOT** be indented.

**Valid Example:**

```php
function findAll() {
    $query=<<<SQL
        SELECT * FROM `table_1`;
SQL;
    // closing identifier should not be indented, although it might look ugly

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This was it for me after seemingly endless matching of opening and closing tags.

Comment: I had a tab character on the same line as the close of my heredoc.  It was really hard to see!

Answer (score 8):

### Look for any loops or statements are left unclosed.

I had ran into this trouble when I left a php foreach: tag unclosed.

```
<?php foreach($many as $one): ?>
```

Closing it using the following solved the syntax error: `unexpected end of file`

```
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Hope it helps someone

Answer (score 6):

Check that you closed your class.

For example, if you have controller class with methods, and by accident you delete the final bracket, which close whole class, you will get this error.

```
class someControler{
private $varr;
public $varu;
..
public function method {
..
} 
..
}// if you forget to close the controller, you will get the error
```

Answer (score 5):

also, look for a comment // that breaks the closing curly brace

`if (1==1) { //echo "it is true"; }`

the closing curly brace will not properly close the conditional section and php won't properly process the remainder of code.

Answer (score 4):

Avoid this as well `<? } ?>` make sure you put `<?php } ?>`

Answer (score 3):

I saw some errors, which I've fixed below.

This is what I got as being erroneous:

```
if (login())
{?>
<h2>Welcome Administrator</h2>
<a href=\"upload.php\">Upload Files</a>
<br />
<a href=\"points.php\">Edit Points Tally</a>
<?php}
else
{
echo "Incorrect login details. Please login";
}
```

This is how I would have done it:

```
<html>
    some code
<?php
function login()
{
    if (empty ($_POST['username']))
    {
        return false;
    }
    if (empty ($_POST['password']))
    {
        return false;
    }
    $username = trim ($_POST['username']);
    $password = trim ($_POST['password']);
    $scrambled = md5 ($password . 'foo');
    $link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'password');
    if (!$link)
    {
        $error = "Unable to connect to the database server";
        include 'error.html.php';
        exit ();
    }
    if (!mysqli_set_charset ($link, 'utf8'))
    {
        $error = "Unable to set database connection encoding";
        include 'error.html.php';
        exit ();
    }
    if (!mysqli_select_db ($link, 'foo'))
    {
        $error = "Unable to locate the foo database";
        include 'error.html.php';
        exit ();
    }
    $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM admin WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$scrambled'";
    $result = mysqli_query ($link, $sql);
    if (!$result)
    {
        return false;
        exit ();
    }
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array ($result);
    if ($row[0] > 0)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
if (login())
{
echo '<h2>Welcome Administrator</h2>
<a href=\"upload.php\">Upload Files</a>
<br />
<a href=\"points.php\">Edit Points Tally</a>';
}
else
{
    echo "Incorrect login details. Please login";
}
?>
some more html code
</html>
```

Comment: Well the thing is inside if (login ()), I have lot of code to write, this is just a sample. Anyway the first answer here has solved it.  I didn't know that a space has to be put.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: yer just helping anyway yer i did get that but i just like to do it that way. And yer sure

Answer (score 3):

In my case the culprit was the lone opening `<?php` tag in the last line of the file. Apparently it works on some configurations with no problems but causes problems on others.

Answer (score 3):

if you are linux user and running your legacy php website on `apache2` server , then locate this file `/etc/php/<php version>/apache2/php.in` and in case you are executing php script using `php cli` like  `php example.php` then `/etc/php/<php version>/cli/php.ini`

set `short_open_tag = Off`  to
`short_open_tag = On`
and restart your service in case of apache2
`sudo systemctl restart apache2.service`

Answer (score 2):

Also, another case where it is hard to spot is when you have a file with just a function, I know it is not a common use case but it is annoying and had to spot the error.

```
<?php
function () {

}
```

The file above returns the erro `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in` while the below does not.

```
<?php
function () {

};
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not an answer to your code, but an answer to the same error message. It may be helpful for someone.
In my case I had an error 'Parse error: Syntax error, unexpected end of file in my PHP code on line 665'
The problem in my case was on the line with closing 'html'

```
    $html = <<<html
....
            html
```

In version 7.2 closing tag should be WITHOUT spaces before

```
    $html = <<<html
....
html
```

Answer (score 1):

For me, the most frequent cause is an omitted '}' character, so that a function or control statement block is not terminated.

Here are is a way to find such a problem:

**Step 1:**

Create a backup of your source file.

**Step 2:**

Starting from the front of the file, moving forward (or from the back of the file moving backward), remove an arbitrary section of PHP code that starts with a function or control statement block.

**Step 3:**:

Test your code in your usual way or by using an online PHP code checker. **If the error message disappears,** then the last removed section of PHP code contains a function or control statement block that was unterminated. Add the "}" termination. **If the error message remains,** go to Step 2 and continue in the same direction.

Answer (score 1):

To supplement other answers, it could also be due to the auto-minification of your php script if you are using an ftp client like FileZilla. Ensure that the transfer type is set to Binary and not ASCII or auto. The ASCII or auto transfer type can minify your php code leading to this error.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it was an unclosed function.
I had to remove and restore functions one by one to check which one is affecting the code.

I hope someone benefits

Answer (score 0):

If your using parse_ini_file($file) or a routine is rading an .ini file, check if you data is quoted in the ini file. Unquoted data will cause this error. Ex; data1=test will cause the error, data1="test" will not.

Answer (score 0):

I developed a plugin and installed it on a Wordpress site running on Nginx and it was fine. I only had this error when I switched to Apache, turned out the web server was not accepting the `<?`, so I just replaced the `<?` tags to `<?php` then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see it mentioned, but if you get this after creating a new file it may be an issue with the **File Encoding**. Make sure it's set to `UTF-8` or whatever your system expects.