# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file - line 59

Tags: php, wordpress

This error appears up when activating a modified theme in Wordpress:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in C:\xampp\htdocs\wp-content\themes\manifest_v1.1\functions.php on line 59

The functions.php file has been modified to allow "subject" lines to be chosen when posting a comment.

Here is the code:

```
<?php
$cats=array(
1=>'Category 1',
2=>'Category 2',
3=>'Category 3'
);

function showCats($cats){

?>
<select name="commentCats">
<?php
foreach($cats as $key=>$cat){
?>
<option value="<?php print $key; ?>"><?php print $cat; ?></option>
<?
}
?>
</select>
<?php
}
add_action ('comment_post', 'add_comment_fields', 1);
function add_comment_fields($comment_id) {
            add_comment_meta($comment_id, 'commentCats', $_POST['commentCats'], true);
}
function manifest_comment($comment, $args, $depth){
print $depth;
global $cats;
 $catID = get_comment_meta(get_comment_ID(),"commentCats", true);
 $GLOBALS['comment'] = $comment; ?>
   <li <?php comment_class(); ?> id="li-comment-<?php comment_ID() ?>">
     <div id="comment-<?php comment_ID(); ?>">
      <div class="comment-author vcard">
         <?php echo get_avatar($comment,$size='48',$default='<path_to_url>' ); ?>

         <?php printf(__('<cite class="fn">%s</cite> <span class="says">says:</span>'),         get_comment_author_link()) ?>
      </div>

      <?php if ($comment->comment_approved == '0') : ?>
         <em><?php _e('Your comment is awaiting moderation.') ?></em>
         <br />
      <?php endif; ?>

      <div class="comment-meta commentmetadata"><a href="<?php echo htmlspecialchars( get_comment_link( $comment->comment_ID ) ) ?>"><?php printf(__('%1$s at %2$s'), get_comment_date(),  get_comment_time()) ?></a><?php edit_comment_link(__('(Edit)'),'  ','') ?></div>
      <?php if($catID){ ?>
      <h3><?php 

      print $cats[$catID]; ?></h3>
    <?php } ?>
      <?php comment_text() ?>

      <div class="reply">
         <?php comment_reply_link(array_merge($args, array('depth' => $depth, 'max_depth' => $args['max_depth']))) ?>
      </div>
     </div>
<?php 
} 

?>
```

I can't figure out what the problem is, I have been told it was working on another test machine. I am currently testing the theme on a local machine. I am testing using XAMPP (http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html) which includes Apache, MySQL, PHP and PHPmyAdmin. I am using a fresh installation of Wordpress version 3.4.1.

Thanks!

Comment: I added in all missing semicolons after all statements and I am still getting this error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse error: Syntax error, unexpected end of file in my PHP code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11482527/parse-error-syntax-error-unexpected-end-of-file-in-my-php-code).

Answer (score 3):

Line 36 - you forgot a `;` after the call:

```
<?php printf(__('<cite class="fn">%s</cite> <span class="says">says:</span>'),         get_comment_author_link()) ?>
```

Edit: as I saw from the comments and further looking at the code in eclipse, you are missing quite a few `;` after statements:

```
<?php comment_text() ?>
<?php comment_reply_link(array_merge($args, array('depth' => $depth, 'max_depth' => $args['max_depth']))) ?>
```

Comment: There are a lot of statements that are missing semicolons - Look at the `echo()` calls or the `comment_reply_link()` calls.

Comment: And line 51 `comment_text()`.

Comment: And line 54 `comment_reply_link()`.

Comment: Pretty much every line where OP calls a function.

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone, I didn't write this myself but remembered I could turn to SO as a resource. I'll make these changes and get back to you all. Would + rep if I could!