# PHP "unexpected end of file..." syntax error

Tags: php

I have downloaded a php web application(Studip). When I go to index.php, I get the following error:

`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in /var/www/html/studip/public/index.php on line 248`

I have checked the syntax, there is no syntax error. Is there anything else that causes this error?

Here is the file:

```
<?php
# Lifter002: TODO
# Lifter007: TODO
# Lifter003: TODO
# Lifter010: TODO
/**
 * index.php - Startseite von Stud.IP (anhaengig vom Status)
 *
 * This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or
 * modify it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as
 * published by the Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of
 * the License, or (at your option) any later version.
 *
 * @author      Stefan Suchi <suchi@gmx.de>
 * @author      Ralf Stockmann <rstockm@gwdg.de>
 * @license     http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html GPL version 2
 * @category    Stud.IP
 */

require '../lib/bootstrap.php';

unregister_globals();

page_open(array('sess' => 'Seminar_Session', 'auth' => 'Seminar_Default_Auth', 'perm' => 'Seminar_Perm', 'user' => 'Seminar_User'));

$auth->login_if(Request::get('again') && ($auth->auth['uid'] == 'nobody'));

// database object
$db=new DB_Seminar;

// evaluate language clicks
// has to be done before seminar_open to get switching back to german (no init of i18n at all))
if (Request::get('set_language')) {
    if(array_key_exists(Request::get('set_language'), $GLOBALS['INSTALLED_LANGUAGES'])) {
        $_SESSION['forced_language'] = Request::get('set_language');
        $_SESSION['_language'] = Request::get('set_language');
    }
}

// store  user-specific language preference
if ($auth->is_authenticated() && $user->id != 'nobody') {
    // store last language click
    if (strlen($_SESSION['forced_language'])) {
        $db->query("UPDATE user_info SET preferred_language = '".$_SESSION['forced_language']."' WHERE user_id='$user->id'");
        $_SESSION['_language'] = $_SESSION['forced_language'];
    }
    $_SESSION['forced_language'] = null;
}

include 'lib/seminar_open.php'; // initialise Stud.IP-Session
require_once 'config.inc.php';
require_once 'lib/functions.php';
require_once 'lib/visual.inc.php';
require_once 'lib/classes/MessageBox.class.php';
include_once 'lib/classes/RSSFeed.class.php';
// -- hier muessen Seiten-Initialisierungen passieren --

// -- wir sind jetzt definitiv in keinem Seminar, also... --
closeObject();

if (get_config('NEWS_RSS_EXPORT_ENABLE') && ($auth->is_authenticated() && $user->id != 'nobody')){
    $rss_id = StudipNews::GetRssIdFromRangeId('studip');
    if ($rss_id) {
        PageLayout::addHeadElement('link', array('rel'   => 'alternate',
                                                 'type'  => 'application/rss+xml',
                                                 'title' => 'RSS',
                                                 'href'  => 'rss.php?id='.$rss_id));
    }
}

PageLayout::setHelpKeyword("Basis.Startseite"); // set keyword for new help
PageLayout::setTitle(_("Startseite"));
Navigation::activateItem('/start');
PageLayout::setTabNavigation(NULL); // disable display of tabs

// Start of Output
include 'lib/include/html_head.inc.php'; // Output of html head
include 'lib/include/header.php';

// only for authenticated users
if ($auth->is_authenticated() && $user->id != 'nobody') {

    UrlHelper::bindLinkParam('index_data', $index_data);

    //Auf und Zuklappen News
    require_once 'lib/showNews.inc.php';
    process_news_commands($index_data);

    // Auf- und Zuklappen Termine
    if (Request::get('dopen')) {
        $index_data['dopen'] = Request::option('dopen');
    }
    if (Request::get('dclose')) {
        unset($index_data['dopen']);
    }

    if ($perm->have_perm('root')) { // root
        $ueberschrift = _("Startseite f�r Root bei Stud.IP");
    } elseif ($perm->have_perm('admin')) { // admin
        $ueberschrift = _("Startseite f�r AdministratorInnen bei Stud.IP");
    } elseif ($perm->have_perm('dozent')) { // dozent
        $ueberschrift = _("Startseite f�r DozentInnen bei Stud.IP");
    } else { // user, autor, tutor
        $ueberschrift = _("Ihre pers�nliche Startseite bei Stud.IP");
    }

    // Warning for Users
    $help_url = format_help_url("Basis.AnmeldungMail");

    // Display banner ad
    if (get_config('BANNER_ADS_ENABLE')) {
        require_once 'lib/banner_show.inc.php';
        banner_show();
    }

    // add skip link
    SkipLinks::addIndex(_("Navigation Startseite"), 'index_navigation');

// display menue
?>
    <div class="index_container">
        <table class="index_box">
            <tr>
                <td class="topic" style="font-weight: bold;" colspan="2">
                    <?= Assets::img('icons/16/white/home.png', array('class' => 'middle')) ?>
                    <?= htmlReady($ueberschrift) ?>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <? if ($perm->get_perm() == 'user') : ?>
            <tr>
                <td class="blank" style="padding: 1em 1em 0em 1em;" colspan="2">
                    <?= MessageBox::info(sprintf(_('Sie haben noch nicht auf Ihre %s Best�tigungsmail %s geantwortet.'), '<a href="'.$help_url.'" target="_blank">', '</a>'),
                            array(_('Bitte holen Sie dies nach, um Stud.IP Funktionen wie das Belegen von Veranstaltungen nutzen zu k�nnen.'),
                                sprintf(_('Bei Problemen wenden Sie sich an: %s'), '<a href="mailto:'.$GLOBALS['UNI_CONTACT'].'">'.$GLOBALS['UNI_CONTACT'].'</a>'))) ?>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <? endif ?>
            <tr>
                <td class="blank" valign="top" style="padding-left:25px; width:80%;" id="index_navigation">
                <? foreach (Navigation::getItem('/start') as $nav) : ?>
                    <? if ($nav->isVisible()) : ?>
                        <div class="mainmenu">
                        <? if (is_internal_url($url = $nav->getURL())) : ?>
                            <a href="<?= URLHelper::getLink($url) ?>">
                        <? else : ?>
                            <a href="<?= htmlspecialchars($url) ?>" target="_blank">
                        <? endif ?>
                        <?= htmlReady($nav->getTitle()) ?></a>
                        <? $pos = 0 ?>
                        <? foreach ($nav as $subnav) : ?>
                            <? if ($subnav->isVisible()) : ?>
                                <font size="-1">
                                <?= $pos++ ? ' / ' : '<br>' ?>
                                <? if (is_internal_url($url = $subnav->getURL())) : ?>
                                    <a href="<?= URLHelper::getLink($url) ?>">
                                <? else : ?>
                                    <a href="<?= htmlspecialchars($url) ?>" target="_blank">
                                <? endif ?>
                                <?= htmlReady($subnav->getTitle()) ?></a>
                                </font>
                            <? endif ?>
                        <? endforeach ?>
                        </div>
                    <? endif ?>
                <? endforeach ?>
                </td>
                <td class="indexpage" align="right" valign="top"><img src="<?=$GLOBALS['ASSETS_URL']?>images/blank.gif" width="390" height="100" alt=""></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
<?

    // display news
    show_news('studip', $perm->have_perm('root'), 0, $index_data['nopen'], "", null, $index_data);

    // display dates
    if (!$perm->have_perm('admin')) { // only dozent, tutor, autor, user
        include 'lib/show_dates.inc.php';
        $start = time();
        $end = $start + 60 * 60 * 24 * 7;
        if (get_config('CALENDAR_ENABLE')) {
            show_all_dates($start, $end, TRUE, FALSE, $index_data['dopen']);
        } else {
            show_dates($start, $end, $index_data['dopen']);
        }
    }

    // display votes
    if (get_config('VOTE_ENABLE')) {
        include 'lib/vote/vote_show.inc.php';
        show_votes('studip', $auth->auth['uid'], $perm);
    }
} else { //displaymodul for nobody
    $index_nobody_template = $GLOBALS['template_factory']->open('index_nobody');
    $db->query("SELECT count(*) from seminare");
    $db->next_record();
    $index_nobody_template->set_attribute('num_active_courses', $db->f(0));
    $db->query("SELECT count(*) from auth_user_md5");
    $db->next_record();
    $index_nobody_template->set_attribute('num_registered_users', $db->f(0));
    $index_nobody_template->set_attribute('num_online_users', get_users_online_count(10));

    if ($_REQUEST['logout'])
    {
        $index_nobody_template->set_attribute('logout', true);
    }

    echo '<div class="index_container" style="width: 750px; margin: 0 auto !important;">';
    echo $index_nobody_template->render();
}

$layout = $GLOBALS['template_factory']->open('shared/index_box');

// Pr�fen, ob PortalPlugins vorhanden sind.
$portalplugins = PluginEngine::getPlugins('PortalPlugin');

foreach ($portalplugins as $portalplugin) {
    $template = $portalplugin->getPortalTemplate();

    if ($template) {
        echo $template->render(NULL, $layout);
        $layout->clear_attributes();
    }
}

page_close();

if (is_object($user) && $user->id != 'nobody') {
    $db->query(sprintf("SELECT * FROM rss_feeds WHERE user_id='%s' AND hidden=0 ORDER BY priority",$auth->auth["uid"]));
    while ($db->next_record()) {
        if ($db->f("name")!="" && $db->f("url")!="") {
            $feed = new RSSFeed($db->f("url"));
            if ($db->f('fetch_title') && $feed->ausgabe->channel['title']) {
                $feedtitle = $feed->ausgabe->channel['title'];
            } else {
                $feedtitle = $db->f("name");
            }

            ob_start();
            $feed->rssfeed_start();
            echo $layout->render(array('title' => $feedtitle, 'icon_url' => 'icons/16/white/rss.png', 'admin_url' => 'edit_about.php?view=rss', 'content_for_layout' => ob_get_clean()));
        }
    }
}

echo '</div>';

include 'lib/include/html_end.inc.php';
```

Comment: It's likely to be a missing }

Comment: Temporarily remove line 247 (`include 'lib/include/html_end.inc.php';`). Do you still get that error? If so, the problem might be in there

Comment: Is it required to end the file with `?>`?

Comment: Does your server support short open tags ? Check your ini.

Comment: Given the mojibake above, a suspect an encoding issue might be at play.

Comment: @BrendanLong: No, in fact it's now sort of discouraged (especially when it comes to class definitions). that was the first thing I checked, too: the index.php file of a ZendFW application doesn't have a closing `?>` either

Comment: It's recommended to omit the closing tag to avoid blank and other characters at the end of the file because if there is a space and headers are modified you will get the "headers already sent" notice. It has little to do with whether it's a class definition or not.

Comment: I checked the syntax with eclipse, the only warnings I had were some HTML checks and the short opening tags. Just replace every <? for <?php

Comment: @azizpunjani & Tivie : Thanks. enabling short open tags solved the problem. Please submit your solution as an answer

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parse error: Syntax error, unexpected end of file in my PHP code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11482527/parse-error-syntax-error-unexpected-end-of-file-in-my-php-code)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Does your server support short open tags ? Check your ini. If it doesn't, enable them. If you can't then replace `<?` with `<?php`

Comment: The relevant setting is named `short_open_tag` and it should be set to `On` for those legacy apps that require it.

Answer (score 2):

You may need to change `<?` to `<?php` 
(particulary if you are using localhost)

Answer (score 0):

This just worked nice for me. It avoids xml tags and its ready for replacing.

**Regex**: `(<\?[^(php|xml)])`

Answer (score -2):

The php open tag on line 170 doesnt seem to have an end.

```
    <?

    // display news show_news('studip', $perm->have_perm('root'), 0,$index_data['nopen'], "", null, $index_data);
     ..... ..... ....
     include 'lib/include/html_end.inc.php';
```

So its probably you need a closing tag at the end.