# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in

Tags: php, syntax

I have been trying to create a website for a group, but I ran into some error I don't seem to be able to fix myself. My question is if some of you can find what I am doing wrong, I've been looking and cant seem to find anything left open or anything simular.

Thanks in advance

```
<?php
session_start();

//Loading template power
include_once("../attritiongaming/tpl/class.TemplatePower.inc");

//Linking templatepower to html
$tpl = new TemplatePower("test.html");

//Connecting to database
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=attritiongaming','root', 'solidusaphm8932');
    $db ->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$tpl->assign("name", "Jessey");

//Echo tables
echo 
"<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>ID</th>
<th>firstname</th>
<th>lastname</th>
<th>username</th>
<th>emailadress</th>
<th>edit</th>
<th>remove</th>
</tr>";

//defining page
$page = isset($_GET['action']) ? $_GET['action'] : '';

//Start switch for page
switch ($page)
  {
    case 'edit';

      $tpl->newBlock("edit");

     try
{
  $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=attritiongaming','root', 'solidusaphm8932');
  $db ->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $sql ="UPDATE members SET firstname='firstname' WHERE firstname='jessey'";

  //Secure with PDO
  $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);

  $stmt->bindParam(':firstname', $firstname, PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $stmt->bindParam(':lastname', $lastname, PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $stmt->bindParam(':username', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $stmt->bindParam(':emailadress', $emailadress, PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $stmt->bindParam(':password', $password, PDO::PARAM_STR);

  //execute sql query
  $stmt->execute();
}

//Catch errors and show them.
catch(PDOException $e)
{
  echo '<pre>';
  echo 'line '.$e->getLine().'<br>';
  echo 'file'.$e->getFile().'<br>';
  echo 'Error'.$e->getMessage();
  echo '</pre>';
}

  default:

  $tpl->newBlock("default");

  if (isset($_POST['search'])) 
  {
    $tpl->assign("searchterm", $_POST['search']);
  }

if (isset($_POST['searching']))
{
  $sql ="SELECT * FROM members WHERE username LIKE :search";

  $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);

  $search = $_POST['search']. '%';

  $stmt->bindParam(':search', $search, PDO::PARAM_STR);

  $stmt->execute();
}
  while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) 
  {
    $tpl->newBlock("");
  }

  $sql= "SELECT * FROM members";
$stmt=$db->prepare($sql);

$stmt->execute();

  //Loop show all members
  while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
  {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['ID'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['firstname'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['lastname'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['username'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['emailadress'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td> <a href='?action=edit&id=".$row['ID']."'>Edit</a></td>";
    echo "<td> <a href='?action=remove&id=".$row['ID']."'>Remove</a></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
  }

?>
```

Comment: Probably a missing } - use an editor or IDE that matches up braces, or (at the very least) decent indenting

Comment: you've missed end bracet of your `switch` statement, put `}` at the end

Comment: @RhoHappy That wouldn't do that. It would not parse the file at all (so no errors) and display the code in the browser.

Comment: i know i jus wanted him to edit in the code

Comment: Please indent your code, or get a decent text editor that auto-indent your code for you...... You _will_ find the error.

And, you put semicolon `;` after `case 'edit'`...

Comment: I have fixed the error and seem to ran into another which I got fixed. It seemed to be that some of my friends have been messing around with some of the code. But thanks alot :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parse error: Syntax error, unexpected end of file in my PHP code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11482527/parse-error-syntax-error-unexpected-end-of-file-in-my-php-code)

Answer (score 3):

You haven't closed the switch and there is no "break" at the end of the default case

Comment: You mean before the default case right? There's no need for a break at the end of the default case.

Answer (score 0):

switch case  closing braces is not closed