# PHP -l produce different output for same file

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, ubuntu-14.04

I have a web application I'm moving from a web server to an other.

On the old server I have:

Ubuntu LTS 12
PHP 5.3.28

On the new one 
Ubuntu LTS 14
PHP 5.5.9

One file produce a syntax error on the new server:

http://pastebin.com/5RMq4SU8 (it's huge, don't want to copy past it here)

```
php -l /var/www/AndroidReviews/myapp/plugins/tools.php
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected end of file in /var/www/AndroidReviews/myapp/plugins/tools.php on line 455
```

On the previous one, every thing works fine

I didn't used php for a few years but `php -l` just verify the file without processing the includes right ?

Do you have any idea of what cause this problem, and how to fix it ?

Comment: add `?>` at the end of file

Comment: @HAL9000 already tried, didn't worked

Comment: `?>` at the end is not required in a php file.

Comment: @Antzi Still, [it is a source of the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11482527/parse-error-syntax-error-unexpected-end-of-file-in-my-php-code).

Comment: You really need to start using a template engine.

Comment: Make sure short tags are on `<?=` otherwise, try and change all to `<?php echo` could very well be it.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I needed to change my php.ini to enable short_open_tag It seems to work now

Comment: Great glad to hear it.

Comment: You can either delete your question or I can put an answer in. No biggie ;)

Comment: Please put an answer :)

Comment: @Antzi Seems like they rejected your edit in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure [**short open tags**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php) are on, otherwise change all `<?=` to `<?php echo` and `<?` to `<?php` which is another reason why you're getting an `end of file` parse error.

Or, enable them in your `php.ini` file.

Comment: `<?=` is not the problem, in PHP 5.5 these work even with short tags off. But in the code `<?` is used in line 397 and 399, those won't work without short tags enabled.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider Thank you Gerald, I overlooked those. I've made the appropriate edit. +1

Comment: You missed my point. You are implying that `<?=` will only work with short tags enabled, [which since PHP5.4](http://de1.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag) is no longer the case.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider The OP stated that short open tags were not on, as per comment http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25637773/php-l-produce-different-output-for-same-file#comment40057782_25637773 - OP's PHP may not that version.