# syntax error, unexpected end of file laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-5

I know this question is stupid. I already tried to find this error for several hours. I still can't figure it out what I missing...

```
@extends('app')

@section('content')
    <div class="container">
        <div class="span7 offset1">
            <iframe width="600" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/<?php echo $_POST['id']; ?>" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>

        <div id="tags">
            <?php
            foreach(json_decode($_POST['data']) as $value) {?>
            <h3> <?php echo $value->Name;?> :
                <small>
                    <?php foreach( $value->Times as $times ) {
                        echo gmdate("i:s", $times).'  ' ;
                    }?>
                </small>
            </h3>
            <br>
            <?php}?>

        </div>
    </div>

@endsection
```

error message

```
FatalErrorException in f414a2a722d122735d2198f9a7f0ae6a line 26:
syntax error, unexpected end of file
```

Comment: Can you add the error...

Comment: Give your brackets some space to breathe: `<?php}?>`

Comment: @Rizier123 Thank you!!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse error: Syntax error, unexpected end of file in my PHP code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11482527/parse-error-syntax-error-unexpected-end-of-file-in-my-php-code)

Comment: I didn't find this article. Thanks for your notice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
<?php}?>
```

to

```
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Due to the syntax error. The . Never put }, it will confuse the syntax and you will get error. Connect to HTML via Druppal for more Laravel system or contact Bootstrap for more MySql