# Website error without any changes..? "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file

Tags: syntax-error

I have a Wordpress website that I haven't used in a while - when I tried to access it I just got a blank page.  So I tried to go in to update it via wp-admin I get the following error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in /MY-LOGIN-PATH/public_html/wp-admin/index.php on line 1

I haven't made any changes in a long while and it was up and running before, so I just don't understand what could have changed as I haven't touched it.  I tried to restore it to an earlier date but my backups did not go far enough to when it was ok.

Can anyone point me in the right direction as to what went wrong and how I could fix it?

I'm a newbie - thanks in advance.

Comment: maybe your file got corrupted

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that there's been changes made in the PHP installation on the server?
The top-most two answers here could be a good place to start: [Parse error: Syntax error, unexpected end of file in my PHP code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11482527/parse-error-syntax-error-unexpected-end-of-file-in-my-php-code)