# How can I get my PHP file to stop displaying 'Unexpected $EOF' as an error?

Tags: php

Thanks for having me on Stackoverflow im really enjoying my stay. 
I have decided to use 000webhost as my database. I'm a PHP Beginner. 
I put in my url followed by /Register.php which is the file of my PHP file so that when a user registers it's uploaded to the database.
It has said 'Connection successful' in the past with error lines which I've grown to fix. One I can not fix right now is below:

Here is my php file:

```
<?php
$servername = 'localhost';
$username = 'xxx';
$password = 'xxx';
$database = 'xxx';

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);

// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

echo "Connected successfully";

$query ="INSERT INTO user VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
$statement = mysqli_prepare($conn, $query);

mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "issis" ,$id, $name, $username, $age, $password);
if(isset($_POST['name'])){ 
    $name = $_POST['name']; 
}
if(isset($_POST['username'])){ 
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $username = $_POST["username"];
    $age = $_POST["age"];
    $password = $_POST["password"];

    mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

    $response = array();
    $response["success"] = true;  

    print(json_encode($response));
    printf("%d Row embed.\n", mysqli_stmt_affected_rows($statement));
    mysqli_stmt_close($statement);
?>
```

## HOWEVER

I receive this line of error when viewing it in Google Chrome

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in /storage/ssd1/298/7395298/public_html/Register.php on line 38
```

## And

This when I view it in 000webhost

```
Syntax Error, Unexpected $EOF
```

I'm hopefully under the right impression that once that problem has been rectified the information will be sent to my database successfully.

#### Any help to rectify this error will cause deep gratitude. Thank you so much!

Comment: Next time __format your code__ with indents and count number of `{` and `}`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [parse error syntax error unexected end of file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11482527/parse-error-syntax-error-unexpected-end-of-file-in-my-php-code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your last if was not closed

```
if(isset($_POST['name'])){ $name = $_POST['name']; }
    if(isset($_POST['username'])){ $username = $_POST['username'];
    $username = $_POST["username"];
    $age = $_POST["age"];
    $password = $_POST["password"];

    mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

    $response = array();
    $response["success"] = true;  

    print(json_encode($response));
    printf("%d Row embed.\n", mysqli_stmt_affected_rows($statement));
    mysqli_stmt_close($statement);

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I would tick it but it says that I am not allowed to pick an answer within 3 minutes. My PHP file when run in google chrome now says 'connection successful' however when I enter my information it is not reflecting on the Database.

Comment: there is issue with your code you are binding variable before even initializing them  mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "issis" ,$id, $name, $username, $age, $password);  first initialize variables set their values and then try inserting them in database ,it wont give error but wont work also

Comment: They're initialised at the very beginning of this code. $id is not because it is set as a primary key that auto-increments -- the information is not being sent over. :(

Comment: Would you be open to help me?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
error_reporting(0);
```

this will hide your all error on the page ...

but there is error that you have nor closed the last if tag with curely bracket

```
<?php

    $servername = 'localhost';
    $username = 'xxx';
    $password = 'xxx';
    $database = 'xxx';

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);

// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

echo "Connected successfully";

    $query ="INSERT INTO user VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
    $statement = mysqli_prepare($conn, $query);


    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "issis" ,$id, $name, $username, $age, $password);


    if(isset($_POST['name'])){ $name = $_POST['name']; }

    if(isset($_POST['username'])){ $username = $_POST['username'];
    $username = $_POST["username"];
    $age = $_POST["age"];
    $password = $_POST["password"];

    mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

    $response = array();
    $response["success"] = true;  

    print(json_encode($response));
    printf("%d Row embed.\n", mysqli_stmt_affected_rows($statement));
    mysqli_stmt_close($statement);

    }
?>
```