# PHP code: syntax error, unexpected end of file

Tags: php, php-parse-error

I have been stuck on my code for a while and has tried googling but cannot find whats the problem with my code, can someone help me? It returns the error "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file on line 35".

```
<?php
require_once('template.php');
include ('login.php');
$content = '<h1>Products</h1>';
$query   = <<<END
SELECT * FROM products
ORDER BY created_at DESC
END;
$res     = $mysqli->query($query);

if (isset($_SESSION['userId']) and ($res->num_rows > 0)) {
    while ($row = $res->fetch_object()) {
        $content .= <<<END
        {$row->name} |
            {$row->price}<br>
            <a href="product_details.php?id={$row->id}">Description</a>| 
            <a href="delete_product.php?id={$row->id}" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')"> 
            Remove product</a>|
            <a href="edit_product.php?id={$row->id}">Edit product</a><br>
            </hr>
END;
    }
} 
elseif (($res->num_rows > 0)) {
    while ($row = $res->fetch_object()) {
        $content .= <<<END
            {$row->name}|
                {$row->price}<br>
                <a href="product_details.php?id={$row->id}">Description</a><br>
END; 
    }
}
echo $navigation;
echo $content;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have added space after HEREDOC tag ending.

On line 30:

```
END;
```

Should be only (without space after semicolon):

```
END;
```

Detailed answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61127019/7082164

I would not recommend using HEREDOC, it's not much readable.