# How to access php.ini on linux server using command line

Tags: php, linux, command-line

I need to make some changes to the php.ini file. Can anyone tell me how and where can i find php.ini file on linux based server using Command line?

Comment: `php -i | grep "Loaded Configuration File"`

Answer (score 4):

Just run the following command in the terminal to locate your php.ini file:

```
php -i | grep php.ini
```

Answer (score 0):

just run on your command line

```
php --ini
```

You will get something like

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /etc/php5/cli
Loaded Configuration File:         /etc/php5/cli/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: /etc/php5/cli/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed:      /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/curl.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/pdo.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/pdo_sqlite.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/sqlite.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/sqlite3.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/xdebug.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/xsl.ini
```

Duplicate of [Dude, where's my php.ini?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8684609/wheres-my-php-ini)