# How to get php installation path

Tags: php

How can you find out what the PHP installation path is on a server?

Comment: What specifically are you looking for?  The `mod_php` libraries?  The PHP run-time modules?  Or, the PHP interpreter?

Comment: You'd think a relatively high rep user would know how to ask a question?

Comment: Check this http://serverfault.com/q/237695

Comment: [`phpinfo();` and `php -i` will help you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8684609/dude-wheres-my-php-ini).

Answer (score 78):

In your terminal run the following:

`which php`

http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?which

Running PHP's https://php.net/phpinfo should tell you more about the PHP that's currently running your scripts.

```
<?php phpinfo();
```

put this line into a file and run it on a browser.

Comment: This may or may not answer the OP question.  If php is on the execution path, the location the binary is referenced may not be the install path.

Comment: Adding to @PaulProgrammer , we need to check environment variables, it might be pointing to something different, we need to check the 'Path' variable in environment variables in windows.

Answer (score 28):

In a command prompt, type

> which php
>
> whereis php

Comment: Wrong, for the same reason @tester is wrong.

Comment: Also doesn't work on Windows ;)

Comment: Worked fine on my Windows machine

Comment: You need `where php` on windows bat