# Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Cache_Exception' with message 'The apc extension must be loaded for using this backend

Tags: php, caching, zend-framework

```
#Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Cache_Exception' with message 'The apc extension must be loaded for using this backend !' in C:\xampp\php\indiapost\library\Zend\Cache.php on line 209
1   0.0156  136328  {main}( )   ..\index.php:0
2   0.1542  707624  Zend_Application->bootstrap( )  ..\index.php:26
3   0.1542  707712  Zend_Application_Bootstrap_BootstrapAbstract->bootstrap( )      ..\Application.php:355
4   0.1542  707784  Zend_Application_Bootstrap_BootstrapAbstract->_bootstrap( ) ..\BootstrapAbstract.php:583
5   0.2072  1335704 Zend_Application_Bootstrap_BootstrapAbstract->_executeResource( )   ..\BootstrapAbstract.php:619
6   0.2082  1336064 Bootstrap->_initRegistry( ) ..\BootstrapAbstract.php:666
7   0.2972  2396120 Zend_Cache::factory( )  ..\Bootstrap.php:81
8   0.2972  2396296 Zend_Cache::_makeBackend( ) ..\Cache.php:94
9   0.3012  2432560 Zend_Cache_Backend_Apc->__construct( )  ..\Cache.php:153
100.3012    2432680 Zend_Cache::throwException( )..\Apc.php:59
```

I'm getting this in `Windows 7`
I'm using `php 5.5.14` and `Apache 2.4.10`
 
`Xampp 1.8.3`

Answer (score 1):

You have to install and enable PHP APC extension

Add `extension=apc.so` to your `php.ini`

If you can't find `php.ini` check [Dude, where's my php.ini?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8684609/dude-wheres-my-php-ini).

Answer (score 0):

check if ABC it is loaded, using

```
<?php
phpinfo();
```

if not loaded you have to enable it in your php.ini