# Nicedit: wrong html Format

Tags: php, html, input, formatting, nicedit

I have an email php form that get the message from a input nicedit text.

[image]

in my php headers code I'm using:

```
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
```

everything works fine except if I want to add a link or a picture.

Nicedit translates my message adding backslash() before and after the tags:

```
test a <a =\"http://example.com\" title=\"example\" target=\"_blank\">link</a>
```

Any Idea why is this happening?

Comment: Is it in nicedit or when you submit the form? Could be magic quotes on in your PHP config, http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.what.php

Comment: its happening when I submit the form.. the link doesn't work because is formatted wrong.. Thanks I will check the link

Comment: Yes, it sounds like it is your PHP converting the input, not nicedit. Look in your php.ini file and see if magic quotes is turned on. http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php

Comment: It sounds like this is the problem.. but where I found the php.ini? I am using wordpress

Comment: Here's a thread on how to find that location, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8684609/dude-wheres-my-php-ini. It should be outside of Wordpress.

Comment: I have tried nothing works.. I have also contacted my host and they replayed saying : "We do not support magic_quotes_gpc and it is already disabled in our server."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is escaping the double quotes.

You can use `stripslashes()` to remove them.

If `stripslashes()` does not work then double quote the phrase.

The purpose is to escape double quotes when double quotes are double quoted.

```
$message = "test a <a =\"http://example.com\" title=\"example\" target=\"_blank\">link</a>";
```

Comment: thank you.. I am trying like $email_message .= " ".stripcslashes($comments)."\n"; but not working

Comment: From PHP manual.    Note: If magic_quotes_sybase is on, no backslashes are stripped off but two apostrophes are replaced by one instead.  There is a simple solution, see my edits.

Comment: thanks I have salved using $email_message .= stripcslashes("$comments");

Answer (score 0):

For future Reference the solution was:

```
$email_message .= stripcslashes("$comments");
```