# Php Image compression and crop does not work for above 3mb jpeg

Tags: php, html, phpmyadmin, image-compression

I want people to upload their images to a page, then compress & crop them. Given below is **php code** for **image compression** , which compress the jpeg and download the compressed version. This works fine upto 3mb(4567*2755) but not files above it.

**Edit:**

The message that appears in the server error log is

> [04-Jun-2015 08:10:07 Europe/Paris] PHP Warning: POST Content-Length of 4213306 bytes exceeds the limit of 3145728 bytes in Unknown on line 0

Please help :-(

```
<?php 
$name = ''; 
$type = ''; 
$size = ''; 
$error = '';
function compress_image($source_url, $destination_url, $quality) 
{ 
    $info = getimagesize($source_url); 
if ($info['mime'] == 'image/jpeg') 
    $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($source_url); 
elseif ($info['mime'] == 'image/gif') 
    $image = imagecreatefromgif($source_url); 
elseif ($info['mime'] == 'image/png') 
    $image = imagecreatefrompng($source_url); 
    imagejpeg($image, $destination_url, $quality); 
    return $destination_url; 
} 

if ($_POST) 
{ 
if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) 
{ $error = $_FILES["file"]["error"]; 
} 
else if (($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif") || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg") || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png") || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")) 
{ $url = 'destinationx.jpg'; 
$filename = compress_image($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $url, 40); 
$buffer = file_get_contents($url); /* Force download dialog... */ 
header("Content-Type: application/force-download"); 
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream"); 
header("Content-Type: application/download"); /* Don't allow caching... */ header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0"); /* Set data type, size and filename */ 
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream"); 
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary"); 
header("Content-Length: " . strlen($buffer)); 
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$url"); /* Send our file... */ 
echo $buffer; }
else { $error = "Uploaded image should be jpg or gif or png"; } } ?> 
<html> 
    <head> 
        <title>Php code compress the image</title> 
    </head> 
<body> 
<div class="message"> 
    <?php if($_POST){ if ($error) { ?> 
    <label class="error"><?php echo $error; ?></label> 
    <?php } } ?> 
</div> 

    <fieldset class="well"> <legend>Upload Image:</legend> 
<form action="" name="myform" id="myform" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
    <ul> 
    <li> 
        <label>Upload:</label> 
        <input type="file" name="file" id="file"/> 
    </li> 
        <li> 
            <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="submit btn-success"/> 
        </li> 
    </ul> 
</form> 
</fieldset> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: What's in the server error log?

Comment: There is no server error log, the server uploads the photo & returns nothing

Comment: There will be a server error log. It's a file on your server. Its location varies so I don't know where yours will be. Find it. It will tell you what has gone wrong.

Comment: [04-Jun-2015 08:10:07 Europe/Paris] PHP Warning:  POST Content-Length of 4213306 bytes exceeds the limit of 3145728 bytes in Unknown on line 0

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP configuration is limiting the size of POST data to about 3Mb. To load a larger file you need to change a couple of items in [PHP.INI](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.php). You can determine the location of PHP.INI with [php_ini_loaded_file()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.php-ini-loaded-file.php) - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24342463/1864610)

[post_max_size](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size) sets the maximum size of a POST. This refers to *all* the data in a POST - uploaded file(s) and any form variables. This will need to be raised to about 5Mb (larger if you want to handle bigger files)

You'll probably also need to set [upload_max_filesize](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-max-filesize) to something larger, but smaller than `post_max_size`. Again, determine the size of files you're likely to need and set accordingly.

These values are usually set in the system-wide PHP.INI file. Some are configurable through `.htaccess` or a PHP.INI file in the application directory; others can be set programmatically with [ini_set()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php). The references I have linked to will tell you where you can set different parameters. The reference for the configuration mode settings is [here](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.modes.php)

Note that some hosting companies limit what you can do on their cheap (or free) hosting packages. You might not be able to change anything if you're on a free package. There's no work around: get a better host, and pay if necessary.