# unable to proceed in drupal installation due to these errors

Tags: mysql, sql, drupal-7

[The following error occurs--](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eWfn5.jpg)

initially i encountered the AJAX error: 200, that still remains, but the installation proceeded further.. and now i encountered this error. unable to install the modules.

Answer (score 0):

The ajax error on install is often due to the execution time in your php.ini being too low. Change it to 2/3mins or more if your environnement is not the production one. The modules install problem might be linked.

Comment: how do i change? please, details?

Comment: Inside the php.ini file, change it to : max_execution_time = 240. http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time

Comment: If you wonder where is your php.ini file take a look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8684609/dude-wheres-my-php-ini