# Php include is doing something very strange

Tags: php, apache

I just set-up a new server and moved all my files across; in it I have the following line of code :

```
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/config/log.php');
```

Now if I leave it as it is I get an error that the log is not included, if I die('msg') before it with a message I will see the message; If I die after it I get nothing;

p.s. My path is correct; and even if it was't I would probably get an error ; which I am not !

Comment: sorry if my question is too direct; I have been up for 20 hours now;

Comment: I don't suppose log.php has an "exit()" call in it, does it?

Comment: no; its some server thing !

Comment: So `echo is_file($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/config/log.php');` is `true`?

Comment: You say "if I leave it as is I get an error" then you say "my path is correct; and even if it wasn't I would probably get an error ; which I am not" -- which is true?

Comment: What is the error? What is the content of `log.php`? Small enough to post?

Comment: there is a error in yur log.php file. run it separately or use die inside log.php to see where the error occurs

Comment: I think I figured it out ! my server company setup a server for me and they didnt enable short_open_tag; I was coding with <? and it wasnt geting read

Comment: You can use : getcwd(); http://php.net/manual/en/function.getcwd.php

Comment: okay so it work when I enable short_open_tag in php.ini; its such a shame that php just ignore it instead of returning an error!

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing this during migration and the path is absolutely correct; meaning there is no include error in debug mode & in log file; then probably you need to check the code in the included file.

Now IF that file uses any type of short opening tag e.g. `<?` instead of `<?php`

Then you have two choices:

1. Not to use short opening tag
2. Or [Locate php.ini](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8684609/dude-wheres-my-php-ini) file and [set `short_open_tag` to on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185320/how-to-enable-php-short-tags)

p.s. dont forget to restart your Apache server.

Answer (score -1):

You can try (tested)

```
$path=$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/config/log.php';
include $path;
```

Comment: You are essentially doing the same thing as the OP's `include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/config/log.php');` How would your solution be better or more likely to work?

Comment: This should be exactly equivalent

Comment: like I explained I had to enable short_open_tag in php.ini