# PHP is working even without php.ini

Tags: php, xampp

I have installed php by XAMPP and now I want to install the Phalcon dll, I have to add it to my php.ini

I did [all the Phalcon installing steps](https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/install.html#windows) but I did not get it is not working; I even removed my php.ini content and restarted Apache but php is still working!

**IS PHP able to work without php.ini?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dude, where's my php.ini?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8684609/dude-wheres-my-php-ini)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How PHP is working without php.ini?

`php.ini` file is not mandatory for PHP to work. It allows you to set up certain parameters, but if there's none then PHP defaults apply.

> Why my php.ini is not working?

You are most likely playing with wrong one. Run script with

```
<?php
phpinfo();
```

and then look for location of `php.ini`. This will be the file you need to edit.

Answer (score 1):

Run this code:

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

to get full path to your php.ini file you are using

Answer (score 0):

Use `phpinfo()` to check details and the path to `php.ini`:

```
<?php phpinfo() ?>
```

---

[`phpinfo()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php):

> Outputs information about PHP's configuration
>
> Because every system is setup differently, phpinfo() is commonly used to check configuration settings and for available predefined variables on a given system.