# Failed to load PDF document in php using DOMPDF

Tags: php, jquery, html, codeigniter, dompdf

My pdf is having 300+ rows. When I tried to load the PDF on my local server, it worked fine. But when I tried to load the PDF on my live server, it showed "Failed to load PDF document". I'm using `DOMPDF` and `codeigniter`.

Can you help me, please?

Thanks!

Comment: We need more details than just this. An eg would be, adding your code that triggers this. Do not paste the whole website code, but create [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: $this->db->select("pxtype,(casecode) as casecodex,patientname,concat(dischadate,' ',dischatime) as discha ,hmoname, 
            (select sum(totalamt) FROM ". inpatient_ipd_vw ." where Start2 <> 'MI' and Start2 <> 'PD' and Start2 <> 'PF' and casecode = casecodex) as ACTUALHOSP,
            (select sum(totalamt) FROM ". inpatient_ipd_vw ." where Start4 = 'PDPP' and casecode = casecodex ) as PHICHOSP")

Comment: I have 6 nested select statements. When I tried to load a pdf for less than 10 rows, it works fine. But when I tried 300+ rows then that's the time it shows the error.

Answer (score 0):

if it is working properly in local server, then it also work on live server.

When you are working on live server, it has request time out duration, if the DOMPDF not giving response within time then you show that page.

you need to put the php.ini on the server and in php.ini you have to change this

> upload_max_filesize = 2M  ;or whatever size you want
>
> max_execution_time = 60 ; also, higher if you must - sets the maximum
>   time in seconds

use -1 for the infinite time, you can set time whatever your pdf files takes to generate output.

To check and setup php.ini on your server here is your reference
[Dude, where's my php.ini?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8684609/dude-wheres-my-php-ini)

Another option is genrate html and put it in view and print that file, that is the fastest and easy way to do it.

check this
https://scotch.io/@nagasaiaytha/generate-pdf-from-html-using-jquery-and-jspdf

Comment: max_execution_time=-1
max_input_time=-1
memory_limit=1000M

These are my configuration but it still doesn't work.

Comment: phpinfo(), and check phpini path

Comment: Where should I put that phpinfo() in my php.ini @Astound? Thank you!

Comment: No @AlynnaPajaron just print in any controller and check the info


check my answer i have updated