# PHP memory getting issue

Tags: php, macos, composer-php

From Mac terminal when I run `php -r "echo ini_get('memory_limit').PHP_EOL;"`, the output is being `128M` but when running `sudo nano /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.26/conf/php.ini`, I can see different memory information, which is `memory_limit = 1G` (which I set myself before). The problem is I want to make sure that greater amount of memory is set, because I keep having this error:

> PHP Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1610612736 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 33 bytes) in phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/RuleSetGenerator.php on line 138

when running command like `composer require symfony/var-dumper`

Any suggestions?

Comment: You might have two versions of php installed. Check this answer to find where the second install might be. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8684609/dude-wheres-my-php-ini

Comment: @OrlandoP. Thanks! Running `php --ini` has endeed helped me know where `128M` is coming from. Now I've been able to set memory_limit to -1 resolving the error

Comment: You can also set the `COMPOSER_MEMORY_LIMIT` environment variable if you only want to change the memory limit that is used when running Composer.