# wamp server apache doesn't contain php.ini file

Tags: php, apache, curl, wamp

I want to uncomment curl in php.ini file of apache and php so I follow this steps.

1. Close WAMP (if running)
2. Navigate to WAMP\bin\php(your version of php)\
3. edit php.ini
4. Search for curl, uncomment extension=php_curl.dll
5. Navigate to WAMP\bin\Apache(your version of apache)\bin\
6. edit php.ini
7. Search for curl, uncomment extension=php_curl.dll
   8 ) Save both
8. Restart WAMP

Upto step no 4 I have done. But I can't find php.ini file in apache\bin.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you use the command line?

Comment: I haven't used yet.

Comment: Is this on a shared host server, on your personal computer, or somewhere else?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where can I find php.ini?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8684609/where-can-i-find-php-ini)

Comment: It's in shared host server.

Comment: Thanks. Let me try. Is it possible that without php.ini file in apache my curl command doesn't work??

Comment: If you have access to cPanel, you can enable cURL settings from there too.