# How to fix PDOException “could not find driver”

Tags: php

> I cant connect PDO and i try to fix my php.ini
>
> when i use `php --ini` on cmd

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path:
Loaded Configuration File:         (none)
Scan for additional .ini files in: (none)
Additional .ini files parsed:      (none)
```

> I try to fix php.ini but didn't find extension
>
> and my php version is

```
PHP 8.2.16 (cli) (built: Feb 13 2024 18:45:00) (ZTS Visual C++ 2019 x64)
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.2.16, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
```

> My PDO Code is

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=registration_system", $username, $password);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    echo "Connected successfully";
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

Comment: This is more a server configuration question than PHP question. Have you looked at doc, https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.installation.php? To give an answer more details would be needed

Comment: Well, probably, if you mistyped the driver name in connection I think you also could get that. What does `php -r "phpinfo();" | grep 'pdo' -i` give you (presuming linux based system)

Comment: Can you show us the code where create the PDO object? Especially the [Data Source Name](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php) is of interest. Please add that code to your question, don't add it in a comment.

Comment: you want to run `phpinfo()` on webserver if that's what you're using, not cmdline.

Comment: You dont seem to have a `php.ini` or its not in the right place. What OS are you using

Comment: Don't know where your php.ini is?  [A search turns up many answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8684609/where-can-i-find-php-ini). `PDOException “could not find driver”`? [A search turns up many answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2852748/pdoexception-could-not-find-driver) (it even includes answers about how to find php.ini).

Comment: OK, so you're trying the MySQL driver. Can you check whether it is installed? See: [PDO::getAvailableDrivers](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.getavailabledrivers.php)