# How can I stop multiple Apache instances on Windows sharing session information

Tags: php, windows, apache, session-variables

I have two instances of Apache installed as services, using different .conf files and listening on different ports. This is to host version 2 of our software while still having version 1 available for support on our test system.

Everything works OK, except if I log into both instances, PHP session information is being shared across the two sites. This is a problem, as links to cases in our V1 database are showing up on the V2 page.

I suspect that the session info is being stored on the server in the same place for both instances. I think this is a PHP variable - is there any way that I can set this value in the Apache CONF file?

(I am not using Virtual Hosts).
Thanks.

Comment: Set one of the instances to use a different location for the session files. It is in the .conf file for Apache. See here (possible duplicate) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4927850/location-for-session-files-in-apache-php

Comment: If they're both storing session data in the same location then change one instance to use another location.  Additionally, configure one instance to use a different name for the session ID cookie (it defaults to PHPSESSID)

Comment: Quite a lot of the code uses the session variable names, so I didn't want to change that, but I have found how to set the location (ironically after an hour of searching fruitlessly, found it 2 minutes after posting this question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the replies. I didn't know where to set the path in the Apache config rather than the PHP.INI, but I have set it here and it works:

```
<IfModule php5_php5.c>
  php_value session.save_path "C:\APACHE\sessions\v2"
</IfModule>
```

Thanks again.